# Split array (uneven chunks) when item value ends with " ago"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to split an array into uneven chunks. Every new array ends with item that has  `ago`(space ago) in the value.

```
const arrExample = [
  "Blah","559","86,758","4.05","2.38","-4.48%","-0.44%","13,562","30d ago", 
  "Trall","531","210,676","16","15","-3.8%","4,955","403d ago", 
  "Shibu","506","991,748","84","6.71%","5,897","667d ago",
  "Mommy","404","35,083","1.64","1.64","-8.38%","17%","7,378","323d ago",
  "Rocket","403","274",".4088",".355","-","-","483","47h ago"
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your input array to find the positions where chunks start and end using `String.prototype.endsWith()`. Then we can use the native `Array.prototype.slice()` method to extract the entire chunk and push it into the results all at once... which should be more efficient than creating a sub array for each chunk and resizing it as we push each individual value -particularly with larger input and chunk sizes.

```js
const input = [
  "Blah", "559", "86,758", "30d ago", 
  "Trall", "531", "210,676", "16", "15", "403d ago",
  "Shibu", "506", "991,748", "6.71%", "667d ago",
  "Mommy", "404", "35,083", "323d ago",
  "Rocket", "403", "47h ago"
];
const output = [];
const length = input.length; // caching length can improve performance
let start = 0, end = 0; // loop control and chunk bounds
while (end < length) {
  if (input[end++].endsWith(" ago")) { // test for EOR and post-increment end
    output.push(input.slice(start, end)); // slice & push chunk (excluding end)
    start = end; // set the next start position
  }
}
console.table(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><script>console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false})</script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block;}</style>
```

Note: `Array.prototype.slice()` extracts up to but does not include `end`. This allows us to simplify our loop control and reduce operations.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will help, if i get you right

```
const result = [];
let acc = [];
for (let item of arrExample) {
    acc.push(item);
    if (item.endsWith(' ago')) {
        result.push(acc); // if last element can be without ' ago' you should check emptyness of acc after cycle
        acc = [];
    } 
}
```